# Kubuntu unrecoverable freezing

Tags: ssd, freeze, kubuntu

I have a fresh Kubuntu 18.04 installation on an external ssd that I have been using to boot linux for almost a year now.

Ive used an installation of Ubuntu 18.04 till now without any problem but ever since I installed the new OS, the system randomly just freezes. No response from either the mouse or the keyboard. I have to do a hard reboot to make it work again. I don`t even have to be doing resource intensive work. It can happen even on an empty workspace.

I have a feeling it might be my SSD failing but it worked pretty well till now with the previous OS installation. I have noticed that when it happens the disk operation LED on the SSD stops blinking almost as if kubuntu isn`t even reading from it. My question is if there is any reason that this could happen? Something that changed with the KDE desktop or USB or power settings that the SSD gets disconnected while being used?

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked /var/log/syslog for any error messages prior to the freezing?

You could also try a different USB port or cable.

Another reason might be a defective SSD, but diagnosing SMART data over USB requires some effort in Linux:
https://www.smartmontools.org/wiki/USB